# writing to res from another function in express

Tags: node.js, express, response

I didn't know how to describe my problem better.
maybe the code will (it's pretty basic)

```
// in users route
var LIST = require('list.json')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.write('beginning list')
  writeList(function() {
    res.end('list printed')
  })

})

function writeList(cb) {
  // some stuff
  res.write(LIST)
  cb()
}
```

so in tldr:

I want to write to the res object in a function other than the main routing handler. why doesn't this work? (`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`)
How is it done properly?

Thanks :)

Comment: Couple of things stand out to me.
1. When I try that, I get `TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer`.
Here is what I tried:
```app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.write('beginning list')
  res.write(['red', 'white', 'blue'])
  res.end()
})```
2. You don't appear to be passing the `res` object to the `writeList` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing res to your function, but trying to write to it, so there is an exception thrown which closes the response object and sets headers to error, and when you calling res.end(), it is already closed, so you are getting headers already set error.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    res.write('beginning list');
    writeList( function(err, writeResult) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.end('Error');
        }
        else{
            res.write(writeResult)
            res.end('list printed')
        }
    })

});

function writeList(cb) {
    // some stuff
    cb(null, LIST)
}
```

Comment: that's what i thought. thanks. if i want to go on writing to res in the ```router.get``` method, i just do something like ```var res = writeList(res, function() // ... ``` and ```return res```from writeList?

Comment: If you want to write to res object in the get, just put the line res.write(LIST), in the get, instead of calling writeList.

Comment: what i pasted up there is not the *actual* code, just very simplified to show what i want to do. there's a rather complex logic involved in ```writeList```, which i want to keep separate. that's why i want to have only status-messages and method-calls in the get, but also have ```writeList```being able to write its status to the res.

Comment: if so, i Would move the writeList to separate file, let's say logic.js, and keep it asynchronous, i.e. pass callback to it, as you are doing now. and make the writeList, generate the list ,and return it on the callback, and then set the genrated list result in the route, I will edit the code...

Comment: well that's what i was trying to say: the whole problem is, that i want to print updates INSIDE of ```writeList``` (like ```empty row```, ```step 25 failed``` etc) in real time.

but.. right now i'm starting it's probably not realtime anyway.. right? it's just a buffer that gets sent as a whole on ```.end()```?